# How to return an element from within an array

Tags: javascript

So I'm building a Tic Tac Toe game, and I want to be able to select a random tile.

I can choose a specific tile and everything works great

`document.getElementById("b5").value = opponentTile()`

but nothing happens when I try replacing "b5" with my random tile function

`document.getElementById(randomBlankSpace()).value = opponentTile()`

My random function looks like this:

```
const allTiles = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9]

function randomBlankSpace() {
    var blankSpaces = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allTiles.length; i++){
        if (document.getElementById(i).value == ""){
            blankSpaces.push(i);
        }
    }
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * blankSpaces.length)
    return blankSpaces[random]
}
```

Do I need to convert randomBlankSpace() into a string in order for the code to work?  Or is there something else to correct?

Edit: here is my code https://github.com/MorningPants/TicTacToe and the current output https://morningpants.github.io/TicTacToe/

Comment: `document.getElementById(i)` i in your case is a number... do you have element with some id `0` or `1` etc.? Instead of `document.getElementById(i)` should be `document.getElementById(allTiles[i])`... and `allTiles` should be array of strings

Comment: I am getting an error in the console saying your callback functions for the click events are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

As @demo points out, your code looks for elements with id `0`, `1`, ..., but you want to look for elements with id `b1,` b2`, ...  The result is that none of the elements are  found, so` blankSpaces`remains empty, and then you dereference`blackSpaces[0]`which returns`undefined` and probably causes an error elsewhere.

I believe that you wanted to write the following code:

```js
const allTiles = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9']

function randomBlankSpace() {
    var blankSpaces = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < allTiles.length; i++){
        if (document.getElementById(allTiles[i]).value == ""){
            blankSpaces.push(allTiles[i]);
        }
    }
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * blankSpaces.length)
    return blankSpaces[random]
}
```

There are two changes from your code.  First, `allTiles` is defined as an array of strings.  (I'm not really sure what it would do before this change; maybe legacy behavior for referring to elements on the page?)  Second, instead of using `i` directly, the code uses `allTiles[i]`.

This code can be simplified in modern ECMAScript as follows:

```js
const allTiles = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'b5', 'b6', 'b7', 'b8', 'b9']

function randomBlankSpace() {
    var blankSpaces = [];
    for (const tile of allTiles) {
        if (document.getElementById(tile).value == ""){
            blankSpaces.push(tile);
        }
    }
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * blankSpaces.length)
    return blankSpaces[random]
}
```

Comment: In the simplified version, you wrote `blankSpaces.push(tile);`--
is this correct or did you mean  `blankSpaces.push(allTiles[tile]);` ?

Comment: I meant `blankSpaces.push(tile);`.  See [JavaScript for...of loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), which iterate over the values of an array instead of their indices.